# Error while calling saveChanges

Tags: entity-framework

I received the following error while adding new record

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException was caught
HResult=-2146233087
Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
Source=EntityFramework
StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at Navigation.RepositoryBase`2.Add(T entity) in c:\Users\afahmy\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Navigation\REpositoryBase.cs:line 174
InnerException: System.Data.UpdateException
   HResult=-2146233087
   Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
   Source=System.Data.Entity
   StackTrace:
        at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
        at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
        at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
        at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
        HResult=-2146232060
        Message=Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Priorities'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Priorities'. The duplicate key value is (55c9b08f-1133-4246-9d0b-4f3e5192ffa5).

The statement has been terminated.
        Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
        ErrorCode=-2146232060
        Class=14
        LineNumber=1
        Number=2627
        Procedure=""
        Server=dbsrv
        State=1
        StackTrace:
             at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
             at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
             at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
             at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
             at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
             at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
             at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
             at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
             at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
             at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
             at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
        InnerException:
```

The code as follows

```
public virtual OperationResult Add(T entity)
    {
        OperationResult opStatus = new OperationResult { Result = QueryResult.Succeeded };

        try
        {
            DataContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
            opStatus.Result = (DataContext.SaveChanges() > 0) ? QueryResult.Succeeded : QueryResult.Failed;
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            opStatus.ExceptionMessage = string.Format(" Error Adding {0}", exp.Message);
            opStatus.Result = QueryResult.Failed;
        }

        return opStatus;
    }
```

Comment: here is the reason: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Priorities'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Priorities'. The duplicate key value is (55c9b08f-1133-4246-9d0b-4f3e5192ffa5)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the `entity` object has been fetched from the database before. If you add it to the context it will get `EntityState.Added`, which means that EF will try to insert it. And apparently you generate a primary key value client-side (i.e. not in the database), so EF tries to insert it with an existing PK value.

Since this is the `DbContext` API (apparent from the Set method, but always helpful to tag explicitly) you can use the [`IDbSetExtensions.AddOrUpdate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846520%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method to let EF figure out whether the object needs to be inserted or updated.

Comment: I have added newid() in each table   and  [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }   and it worked

Comment: Now no exceptions but when I add new row any navigation property in the entity add a new row and i need to add it as a foreign key please help

Comment: I would need more information about the nav properties for that. You better ask a new question containing the essential info, because it's also a new issue.

Comment: I have an employee class  public class Employee : InterTechBaseEntity
    {
        public Employee()
        {
          
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual Confidentiality Confidentiality { get; set; }

        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Just set the nav properties with existing or new objects (`Confidentiality` and/or `Department`). EF will take care of the foreign keys.

Comment: this is the problem when i set nav property each time it adds a new row (in department for example) despit of it exist I need to know how I link existing nav property to the entity thanks fro your help

Comment: Well, this really is a new question. A post should not divert into a new issue. Your original question has been answered.