# Error when calling EF SaveChanges() on EC2, same application/DB works locally

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, amazon-ec2

I have an ASP.NET application that uses a SQL Server Express database on AWS RDS.

I run the application locally with the connection string pointing the RDS instance and it works.

When I publish the application and move it to an EC2 instance I get the error below when calling certain APIController Actions that use `SaveChanges()`.  Some actions work that use `SaveChanges()` but most don't and throw this error.  I am using the same exact code and RDS database from my local machine and I don't get this error.

```
An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

 at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update
(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)\r\n at 
System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)\r\n at 
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()

  at MyApplication.Controllers.ValuesController.MyAction(MyObject myobject)

InnerException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner 
   exception for details.<br><br>   at   
 System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update
  (IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
    at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011166/error-while-calling-savechanges) link talks about the same error but the solution didn't work for me.

[This](http://forums.asp.net/t/1875159.aspx?Weird%20Exception%20when%20i%20execute%20insert%20update%20command%20to%20my%20site%20in%20a%20shared%20hosting%20envionment%20) link is about the same error but says it's a problem with the hosting solution.

Comment: Show inner exception

Comment: I added the inner exception.  It's the same as the exception.

Comment: We need to go deeper :) add inner and inner while you get more informative one

Comment: I don't know exactly what the exception was because it went away after I did the following, starting with your advice to go deeper into the exceptions.  I used `GetBaseException()` to get the first exception.  Before I deployed the change to the AWS server, I also updated from `EF5` to `EF6`.  I removed the old model `EDMX` and made a new one.  After that it worked.  I also was creating Entity contexts in functions that get called frequently so I wrapped them in `using()` blocks.